# How would a blood bound Wight behave?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

So, this would be the question. The rules of the [blood bond](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Blood_bond_%28VTM%29) are very clear,  I didn't find too much from the [Wights](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Wight).

I think, for a vampire with enough low [Humanity](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Humanity_%28VTM%29), it would be a highly interesting thing, making some Wights (or making some childer by illegal embraces and then tricking them through the [wassail](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Wassail)), blood bound them, and then construct an army from them. They don't fear, don't think, don't ask. Don't frenzy (or, they are in continous frenzy). Can't be manipulated, they fight until the last blood.

Well, I surely wouldn't allow it to a vampire character with humanity 1+. It is probably a hardcore thing even with the eyes of the sabbat elders. Their mass embraces produce cannon fodders with low humanity, but not Wights.

But, what now currently is interesting to me: can a wight be blood bound? How would it behave? I think, for the Beast is it maybe not really important to satisfy the regent. But what if it is a blood-bound Beast?

More clearly:

1. Would a Wight Thrall follow the wishes of its Regent?
2. Would a Wight Thrall be capable to harm its Regent intentionally?
3. Would it be capable to understand, what its Regent says him?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Would a Wight Thrall follow the wishes of its Regent?

No.  They are frenzying kindred.  They, at most, could be swayed by a regent's suggestions a little bit more than anyone else.  But they are driven by their beast's desires - to hunt and hide.

## Would a Wight Thrall be capable to harm its Regent intentionally?

If the beast decided that the regent is a threat, it will make that attempt, and have the same chance of success as any other thrall in frenzy.  Further, considering what you would have to do to break them of much of their humanity (but not all of it, see further in this post), the Regent is likely to be the first thing the Wight attacks.  Again, it is the beast in the drivers seat of the body, full time.

## Would it be capable to understand, what its Regent says him?

Yes, but they won't care.

## Could I actually make a Wight in the first place?

Ok, you didn't ask this, but it is the elephant in the room.  The answer to this is a simple no, not without the subject being a knowing willing participant - before they are bound.  There is a point where self-preservation and the control of others becomes a justification to prevent degeneration.  The character has to believe they had a choice to actually degenerate to the lowest levels - thats the key to the lower levels - willful disregard for humanity.

Comment: Ok, but where is it referenced, that the blood bond binds the human, and not the beast? Btw, somewhere I've read, multiple Wights can create packs, where the strongest wight is a leader, and the others defend their leader until death (if you want I can dig out the reference). This means, they _are_ capable to understand some type of a hierarchy, although it is not more as a flock. The Wight can also remember what it knew before the wassail (for example, although it hasn't any problem to commit diablerie, it will only do if it knew it as a sentient being).

Comment: Canon example: [Velja the Vivisectionist and Elaine Cassidy](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Velya_the_Vivisectionist_and_Elaine_Cassidy)